# Scala Immutable Array Filter Condition

Tags: scala, filter, adjacency-matrix

I am working with an adjacency matrix in a project and I need to remove an edge safely.

The project I am working on uses the matrix in the following way:
`Map[Agent, Array[Edge]]`. I would like to use the `Array.filter` function to remove the edge in question. I am doing this to avoid using indexing or `zipWithIndex`.

After adding four "agent"s to the matrix and adding two undirected edges this is what my matrix looks like:

```
A1: null, 1.1, null, null, 
A2: 1.1, null, null, null, 
A3: null, null, null, 1.2, 
A4: null, null, 1.2, null,
```

As you can see the edges are (A1, A2) and (A3, A4).

To remove edge (A1, A2) I am using this:

```
map = map.updated(a1, map(a2).filter(e => e != null && e.toAgent != a2))
```

However, this is removing the null entries (as expected). This is what my matrix looks like after removing an edge using the above technique:

```
A1: 1.1, 
A2: 
A3: null, null, null, 1.2, 
A4: null, null, 1.2, null,
```

The role of null entries is **important** because it allows for me to quickly insert new edges in their correct location. I am looking for a solution to filtering out a single edge.

The problem with simply doing:

```
map = map.updated(a1, map(a2).filter(e => e.toAgent != a2))
```

Is that I am operating on null entries which causes a `NullPointerException`  (obviously). I am looking for a solution to this.

To reiterate, I want to filter using an attribute of each edge that may or may not be null. Is there a way to implement a type of *"skip if null"*?

Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using `Option` rather than having `null` elements. Scala `Option` is a much more powerful and type-safe alternative to `null`.

```
A1: None,      Some(1.1), None,      None, 
A2: Some(1.1), None,      None,      None, 
A3: None,      None,      None,      Some(1.2), 
A4: None,      None,      Some(1.2), None,
```

You can `filter` an `Option` and it will only test `Some` values and skip `None` values.

```
map = map.updated(a1, map(a2).map(_.filter(_.toAgent == a2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the real problem.

The way how you deal with nulls is fine. The problem is that you're trying to use `filter`, which eliminates elements from your collection, shortening it.

If you want to replace certain elements in your collection with nulls, the immutable way to do it is by using `map`:

```
var arr = Array(null, 1.1, null, null)
arr = arr.map(e => if (e == 1.1) null else e)
println(arr.toList)  // List(null, null, null, null)
```

However, note a few things.

1. Array in scala is mutable. Meaning, that you can do following:

   ```
   arr(edgeIndex) = null
   ```

   This will replace your edge with null.
2. Scala has immutable sequence, `Vector`. If you use it instead of array, you can have immutability and indexed updates, like this:

   ```
   var vec = Vector(null, 1.1, null, null)
   vec = vec.updated(edgeIndex, null)
   println(vec) // Vector(null, null, null, null)
   ```